# Timeout when trying to view Audit Log Reports

Tags: sharepoint-server, auditing, time-out

I have enabled auditing in SharePoint 2010. I wanted to create a Report for 'Content Viewing' that should contain a list of who opened which files in SharePoint.

This worked for me in the past. But recently i am getting a timeout exception when trying to create the Reports.

Probably the logs are too big and therefore cause the timeout.What can I do to prevent this and create those Reports anyway?

Comment: Do you found any way to overcome this issue? I am getting same issue.

Comment: I unfortunately could not overcome this issue yet.

Comment: Consider using IIS logs. There are many free tools for parsing these files, e.g. Log Parser Studio from Microsoft. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925690/log-analyzer-tools-for-iis-webserver-logs

Answer (score 1):

This issue happen due to couple of reason.

- Hardware issue, you have huge data but your hardware not supporting it.
- You have the tons of data in Audit log which require more time to processing.

I think, if you have more than 2 months old data then trim the audit log to get the reports. Also if your hardware issue, try to upgrade it.

For trimming you can use the below command:

```
stsadm -o trimauditlog -url <URL name> -date <YYYYMMDD> -databasename <database name> [-databaseserver] <database server name>
```

For more information visit [Unable to view Audit Report](https://zoshaikh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/unable-to-view-audit-report/).

Comment: Using stsadm on Sharepoint 2010 gives `Missing operation name or the operation name is invalid.`.