# Audit log reports - system.web.httpexception request timed out. SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, audit-log-reports

I have enabled auditing in SharePoint 2013. I wanted to create a Report for 'Content Viewing' that should contain a list of who opened which files in SharePoint.

This isn't working for me in. I am getting below error:

> system.web.httpexception request timed out.

I googled for this and found that this can be solved by increasing timeout in *web.config* file. But it didn't help much. Here is my *web.config* settings which I tried lately.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="999999" maxUrlLength="1024" />
```

So I thought probably the logs are too big and therefore cause the timeout. So I created a new site collection in my web application and tried to run same report. But still I am getting same error. We are using high-end configuration for this.

What can I do to prevent this and create those Reports anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try below PowerShell command.

```
stsadm -o trimauditlog    -url <URL name>    -date <YYYYMMDD>    -databasename <database name>    [-databaseserver] <database  server name>
```

Reference Link : https://zoshaikh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/unable-to-view-audit-report/

Comment: Already tried. I have put comment here too
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167198/timeout-when-trying-to-view-audit-log-reports